# Installing dnsmasq with Homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew, dnsmasq

I have installed dnsmasq using Homebrew. All seemed to go fine installing.

After installing I followed the instructions...

`cp /usr/local/opt/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.conf.example /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf`
`sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist`

**The Problem:**
dnsmasq doesn't seem to to bes working. When I run:

`sudo dnsmasq`

I get:

`dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use`

When I run:

`sudo launchctl stop /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist`

I get:

`launchctl stop error: No such process`

Any ideas what is going on or how to tell if it is installed and running correctly?

Comment: Open your Activity Monitor, select All processes and use the filter in order to check that dnsmasq is not already running

Comment: It's not showing up in Activity Monitor.

Comment: I take that back... I hadn't selected "All Processes". It is there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`launchctl stop` takes a job label, not a path (same with launchctl's `stop` and `list` commands). Assuming the label is `homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq`, you can check the daemon's status with `sudo launchctl list homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq` (if it has a PID listed, it's running), and if necessary stop it with `sudo launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq`. If that's not the right label, check in /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist for the string following the `Label` key.

Comment: Great, that helped, thanks. I still can't get dnsmasq to work, although it appears to be running. I'll open another issue.